# sram etap axs compatibility - rival road setup adding SRAM ETAP CLICS

Tags: sram, triathlon

[image]

I am looking at SRAM AXS compatibility chart and I am confused, and can not find support on local shops here in Warsaw, Poland which are mostly Shimano-focused.

I would like to get this [Trek Emonda SL6 etap rival](https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/bikes/road-bikes/performance-road-bikes/%C3%A9monda/%C3%A9monda-sl/%C3%A9monda-sl-6-etap/p/35029/)

And I would like to have an option to use is for triathlons (mostly 70.3 and Olympic distance) so I would like to add triathlon extension bars and would love to put on their ends the [SRAM ETAP CLICS](https://www.sram.com/en/service/models/es-eac-clic-a1).

**QUESTION**:
**And I am not sure if I will be able to make it working together even with [ETAP AXS™ BLIPBOX](https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/es-eac-bbox-d1SRAM) ?**

docs:

- https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/es-eac-bbox-d1
- https://www.sram.com/en/service/models/es-eac-clic-a1
- https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/compatibility-map/road/axs-components-compatibility-map.pdf
- https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/bikes/road-bikes/performance-road-bikes/%C3%A9monda/%C3%A9monda-sl/%C3%A9monda-sl-6-etap/p/35029/

Answer (score 1):

The Rival levers don't have ports for auxillary shifters the way Red and Force do. I don't believe there's a way of making this work with Rival. The derailleurs want to be paired with either a set of Doubletaps or the Blipbox, but I don't think they have any ability to be controlled by both in the same installation.